# a quadratic equation for two unknown number

Tags: quadratic-forms

find values of $p$ such that the equation $4x^2 + 3px - 2p = 0$ has? below are a few choices of the value p:

a) 2 real roots

b) 1 real roots

c) no roots or complex roots

---

so far i did for a) 2 real roots

$$(3p)^2 - 4(4)(-2p) > 0\\
9p^2 +32p > 0\\
9\left( p^2+\frac{32p}{9} \right) > 0\\
p^2+\frac{32p}{9} > 0\\
p^2 +\frac{32p}{9} + \left(\frac{32}{18}\right)^2 > 0\\
\left(p + \frac{32}{18} \right) ^2 > 0 \\
p + \frac{32}{18} > 0\\
p > -\frac{32}{18} $$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! You can quote your formula using $\$\ldots\$$ to associate better display style.

Comment: By the way, your first four equations are valid, but in the shift to the 5th equation, you need to add $(32/18)^2$ to *both* sides, not just the left side.

Comment: thanks, i found that 

(x-a)(x-b)>0

x<a , x>b

but why is x<a ?not x>a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The roots are given by the quadratic formula:
$$
r = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} \\
= \frac{-3C \pm \sqrt{9C^2 + 32p}}{2a} 
$$
If the thing under the square root is positive, you'll get two roots. Under what conditions will you get just one? Under what condition will you get none?

Comment: i am sorry, it meant to be p instead of C

Comment: OK; replace the "C" in the equation above with a "p"; under what conditions is $9 p^2 + 32p$ positive? Negative? Zero?

Comment: when the discriminant is bigger than 0, 2 roots are form

Comment: OK. And when the discriminant is zero, what can you say about $p$? And how many roots do you get?   And can you think of a value of $p$ for which the discriminant is negative?

Comment: when discriminant = 0 , 1 roots

Comment: when discriminant < 0, no roots

Comment: OK. So the discriminant is $9p^2 + 32p$. Can you think of a value of $p$ that makes that be zero? Can you think of a value of $p$ that makes it negative?

Answer (score 0):

$D=(3p)^2+4\cdot4\cdot2p=9p^2+32p=p(9p+32)$

if $D>0$ then there is 2(different) real roots

$D=9p^2+32p=p(9p+32)>0$

$p\in(-\infty;-32/9)\cup(0;+\infty)$

if $D=0$ then there is 1(or 2 equal) real root

$p=0$ and $p=-32/9$

if $D<0$ then there is no roots or 2 complex roots

$p\in(-32/9;0)$

Comment: i don't get it when D > 0  (2 real roots)
p < -32/9
(instead i got p>-32/9 )

Comment: let p=-5 then $D=-5(-45+32)=65>0$ then $x=\frac{15 \pm \sqrt{65}}{2\cdot4}$  it means that $x_1=\frac{15 + \sqrt{65}}{8}$ and $x_2=\frac{15 - \sqrt{65}}{8}$   it's obvious that both roots are real numbers